# How can we elimate break statement in C/C++ programs to support compiler for auto vectorization?

Tags: c++, c

There are some of the rules to be followed while programming, making the program easy for the compiler to auto vectorize.

Some of the rules include:

1. No 'break' statements(The loop should have single flow)
2. No 'if' statements(Only masked assignment allowed) and many other

It would be great to know what steps can be taken in order to replace these conditional break statements.

I would like to give a simple example to make it easy to understand but the program can contain many 'break' statements which are usually depending on rigorous condition and status flags.

Consider a simple program  working on a 2D array:

```
void main()
{
int i,j,sum = 0;
int array[3][5] = {{1,3,6,8,9},{23,65,77,54,5},{2,5,-7,-89,-8}};
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
       sum += a[i][j];
       if(i==2 && j==2)
       {
           break;//breaks out of loop j
       }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you are referring to.

Comment: In the spirit of what @cigien just said: You can start by actually writing the code to do so.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but unfortunately to broad.

Comment: @cigien: The question is not referring to code. It is not asking about specific code. It is asking about principles and methods related to high-performance computing. Please do not treat every question on Stack Overflow as a request for debugging help or a request for help with specific code.

Comment: @JaMiT: The question makes no such assumption, because it is not about specific code.

Comment: Regarding 1, if a loop cannot have a break statement—it must have a single flow, then the loop must always run to completion. So then the question is, how can you write a loop that produces acceptable results even if it must continue to process all elements throughout an array (or whatever else it is iterating over)? As your question mentions masked assignment, one is to mask all unwanted assignments after the loop would have ended. Another is to figure out or mark where the useful results ended. And a mitigation is to design the loop stopping condition to stop somewhat early when needed.

Comment: @JaMiT: “these conditional break statements and if statements” refer to the classes of statements described in rules 1 and 2. It means the classes of those statements generally; it is not a reference to any specific code. It is not a proofreading slip. These are well-known issues in high performance computing.

Comment: @JaMiT: That is just how `break` statements are used. A loop that contains an always-executed `break` statement is not actually a loop.

Comment: @JaMiT: The context is loops. I am no more adamant about my position than you are about yours, and there is reason to be because there is value being lost here. Too many respondents on Stack Overflow are too quick to take questions to the level of debugging code and away from broader conceptual questions. Certainly the phrasing in the question can and should be clarified and improved, but the concepts it is asking about are valuable. By misunderstanding the question, instead of guiding it toward a useful form, Stack Overflow has turned it away and discouraged the questioner.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the subject is indeed very interesting. This question however imho is poorly written and formulated. It just throws some vague and general rules without any substance. The example added just enforces my opinion: the code is not vectorizable with or without `break`. The subject the OP hints at is fascinating. But it requires at least a good chapter to even scratch the surface and requires a lot of more context: the kind of operations, the compiler, the architecture: the answer will greatly differ between x86, sse and a true SIMD (where you don't even have branches). ..

Comment: .. And the answer will not be a simple "do such and such". It would need to be a complex analysis with multiple use cases. Unless the question is very specific. Which brings me back to my point: merely hinting at a good but complex subject does not make a question good.

Comment: @bolov: The disputed issue is not whether the question is good or not. It is whether the question is about specific code or not. This affects whether a proper course of action would have been to ask the OP for specific code or instead the question should have been guided to clarification and rephrasing about the concepts being asked about. I ask people to stop pushing Stack Overflow to being a debugging service. Be more receptive to conceptual questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil with this I agree. 100%.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are indeed very adamant about trying to prove me wrong. Adios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would be great to know what steps can be taken in order to replace these conditional break statements.

Generally speaking, you don't.

A `break` statement within a loop exists to terminate the loop, typically based on a condition other than the loop's normal termination condition. Loops usually have a terminal condition built into them, as well as a specific syntactic place where that condition is found. As such, if the code in question is decently written, a `break` statement will only appear in cases where the additional termination condition cannot reasonably be added to the loop termination condition.

So if we're talking about code that is reasonable (and if we're not, then vectorization is the least of your worries), then rewriting it to fold the `break` condition into the loop condition is either straight-up impossible or will lead to code that is exceedingly difficult to follow/maintain.

So in general, if `break` is being used because it's necessary, then it isn't going to be possible/reasonable to fold it into the loop condition. And even if it is, a complex loop termination condition can kill auto-vectorization just as effectively as a `break` statement.

Most code is not going to be amenable to vectorization. Your trivial example is non-vectorizable because it contains an OS system call as part of its operation. Vectorization typically applies to looping over sequences of values and performing fairly simple operations on them.